# Пользовательские типы в классе сущности на Entity Freamework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

При написании DAL в .NET приложении было принято решение об использовании CodeFirst-подхода EF6. Имеется класс сущности - клиент:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; } //PK
    //...
    //address properties:
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string House { get; set; }
    public string Flat { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

С точки зрения ОО-подхода, имеет смысл инкапсулировать свойства, относящиеся к адресу проживания объекта в отдельный класс для удобства обращения к самому объекту в коде, тогда код примет следующий вид:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; } //PK
    //...
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
     //...
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; } //PK

    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string House { get; set; }
    public string Flat { get; set; }
}
```

И вроде бы всё хорошо, но нужно хранить в самой БД поля со значением адреса как обычные столбцы для каждого клиента в таблице, содержащей данные о клиенте, а не выделять под адреса отдельную таблицу. Но вместе с тем, в самом коде хотелось бы инкапсулировать поля в отдельный класс. Можно ли это сделать при помощи Fluent API или DA? И можно ли вообще? 
Спасибо.

Comment: > нужно хранить в самой БД поля со значением адреса как обычные столбцы для каждого клиента в таблице, содержащей данные о клиенте, а не выделять под адреса отдельную таблицу

Нужно кому?
Адреса будут использоваться в других замапленных сущностях? Если да - то вам всяко потребуется отдельная табличка.

Comment: а чем обусловлена необходимость? я бы по мимо того что `Address `хранил отдельно я бы еще его разбил на `City`,`Street` т.е. отдельные справочники а иначе готовьтесь преодолевать трудности которые сами себе закладываете. а так то что Вы хотите [возможно](http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.5.php) но лучше сделайте **правильно**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто не выделять адрес в отдельную сущность. Модель вида:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; } 

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string House { get; set; }
    public string Flat { get; set; }
}
```

при контексте

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

сгенерирует одну таблицу:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients](
    [ClientId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Address_City] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address_Street] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address_House] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address_Flat] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Clients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClientId] ASC
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

В первом приближении простейший способ, это унаследовать клиента от адреса... Хотя с точки зрения обывательской логики это странновато:

```
public class Address
{
    public String Street { get; set; }
    /// ...
}

public class Customer : Address 
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    /// ...
}
```

Ну и адреса при этом естественно отдельно храниться не будут, и ссылаться на них внешним ключом не будет нужно.

Answer (score 0):

> нужно хранить в самой БД поля со значением адреса как обычные столбцы для каждого клиента в таблице, содержащей данные о клиенте, а не выделять под адреса отдельную таблицу. Но вместе с тем, в самом коде хотелось бы инкапсулировать поля в отдельный класс.

Inheritance with EF Code First:

- Table per Hierarchy (TPH)
- Table per Type (TPT)
- Table per Concrete class (TPC)

примеры и объяснения [тут](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).